# Q: How can I access the coordinate of the point in a boost::segment?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm new to `boost::geometry`. I tried to use the for_each_point to access the point in the `boost::segment` but it's not working. I also tried to use the `segment_view` to to access it but the output of the point is weird.
Is there any mechanism that I can iterate through each point in the `boost:: segment`?

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<int> CleanPoint;
typedef boost::geometry::model::segment<CleanPoint> CleanSegment;
typedef boost::geometry::segment_view<CleanSegment> CleanSegmentView;

BOOST_FOREACH(CleanSegment seg, frontier_cells_){
    CleanSegmentView view(seg);

    //Iterating over the points of this segment
    for (boost::range_iterator<CleanSegmentView const>::type it = boost::begin(view);
                     it != boost::end(view); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << " Point = " << boost::geometry::dsv(*it)<<'\n';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic way of accessing coordinates is via `get`/`set` free functions:

```
pt = point{get<0, 0>(segment), get<0, 1>(segment)};
set<0, 0>(segment, get<0>(pt));
set<0, 1>(segment, get<1>(pt));
```

---

`boost::model::segment<>` is derived from `std::pair<>` so you should be able to access points via `first` and `second` attributes:

```
pt = segment.first;
```

---

`segment_view` should work too, what issues do you have with it? If there is a bug you can report it at [GitHub](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry) or [Boost Trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/newticket).

---

Yes, it seems that currently (Boost 1.64) `for_each_point` is not implemented for Segments. It probably should.

---

You could also use your own type having members you need and adapt it to Boost.Geometry Segment concept:

- [Segment Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_segment.html)
- [geometry::model::segment<> adaptation](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/include/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp#L119-L167)